# Robotframework: kill the process

Tags: testing, selenium-webdriver, robotframework, kill-process, teardown

I try to write test for GUI app throw Winium + Selenium
But main point, that I can't finished process what start throw test.

```
*** Settings ***
Library Process


Suite Setup suite_setup
Suite Teardown  suite_teardown


*** TestCases ***
testcase1

    Click Element   id=btnHome  
    Click Element   id=tbLPN
    Input Text  id=tbLPN    testtext
    Click Element   id=btnManualRequest
    Click Element   id=btnHome  

*** Keywords ***
suite_setup
    Start process   C:\\test\\Winium.Desktop.Driver.exe shell=yes  alias=first
    Start process   C:\\test\\Services.exe  shell=yes  alias=second
    ${procID1} =    Get Process Id  first #here I just checked that alias is working
    ${procID1} =    Get Process Id  second #here I just checked that alias is working


    Import Library  Selenium2Library
    ${winium_host}= Set Variable    localhost
    ${winium_port}= Set Variable    9999
    ${capabilities}=    Create Dictionary   app=C:\\test\\Gui.exe   
    Create Webdriver    Remote  command_executor=http://${winium_host}:${winium_port}   desired_capabilities=${capabilities}
    sleep   8

suite_teardown
Terminate Process  first  True
```

I think that problem is winium, because I try this way with simple calc.exe, and it's working well.

How to kill GUI app? because throw Terminate Process it's not working(

Artem

Comment: I dont understand what you're asking :(

Comment: I asked about how finished process, because GUI app not go down throw command 'Terminate Process'

Comment: What error? can you show me? or does it just do nothing?

Comment: It's don't give me any error message. They perform test case and when go to suite_teardown just waiting for something. Then I can manual finished process in Task Manager and after this my test finished and create report

Comment: I need it for automatized test, and for my way it should be started and finished service.exe and gui.exe every time

Comment: What version of Python are you running? There is a limitation - `Graceful termination is not supported on Windows by Jython nor by Python versions prior to 2.7. Process is killed instead.` And you are calling `first`, which is a graceful termination

Comment: I use Python 2.7.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to kill GUI it's navigate to 'Close' button